# Is order in a subquery guaranteed to be preserved?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, sql-order-by

I am wondering in particular about PostgreSQL. Given the following contrived example:

```
SELECT name FROM
  (SELECT name FROM people WHERE age >= 18 ORDER BY age DESC) p
LIMIT 10
```

Are the names returned from the outer query guaranteed to be be in the order they were for the inner query?

Comment: Due to optimization, it probably would return them in order... but according to the SQL standard, the order of a sub-query does not influence the main query.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, put the order by in the outer query:

```
SELECT name FROM
  (SELECT name, age FROM people WHERE age >= 18) p
ORDER BY p.age DESC
LIMIT 10
```

The inner (sub) query returns a result-set. If you put the order by there, then the intermediate result-set passed from the inner (sub) query, to the outer query, is guaranteed to be ordered the way you designate, but without an order by in the outer query, the result-set generated by processing that inner query result-set, is not guaranteed to be sorted in any way.

Comment: What the hell?! If it refuses to do it why not just throw a syntax error?

Comment: The inner (sub) query returns a result set. If you put the order there, then the intermediate resultset passed from the inner (sub) query, to the outer query, is guaranteed to be ordered the way you designate, but the result set generated by the outer query, by processing that inner query resultset,  is not.

Comment: Interesting subtle point. I implicitly wouldn't expect the order of an ordered result set to be changed unless joined to a second resultset but can see how it may be difficult to second guess the optimiser.

Comment: @Adamantish, and, lots of other stuff can happen in the outer query as well. additional output columns may be  added and/or removed, or processed/transformed. Joins can be performed that create additional rows and/or remove rows. Where clause filters can remove rows. Aggregations can take place using a Group By clause.

Comment: Indeed, but of those only a join to another resultset could logically create an ambiguity over what may be the programmer's desired order. Basically it seems you're saying that once its inside the parens a resultset will be dealt with optimally, treating it like a table i.e. with no particular order. This indeed makes a subquery `order by` meaningless in all but a few cases such as an inner `array_agg`

Comment: Yes, but the point I was trying to make is that ordering the final result-set is a task that makes sense only on the final result-set, not on intermediate result-sets, because, in part, there are so many potential things that can be done in the final outer query. Just one example, what if there are two subqueries being joined together, and each has an order by clause in it?

Comment: I'm not expressing myself very clearly. Let's leave it here. Genuine thanks for the info.

Comment: @Adamantish,  Actually, (not to seem like I'm still disagreeing), I think it was I who was not clear.  But no worries sir, good day to you!

Comment: @CharlesBretana but if you want to have an offset BEFORE doing extra filtering/join/... you would want to order in the subset, then filter, and then you need to order again to guarantee the inner order (that you need because of the offset) to be preserved?

Answer (score 12):

For simple cases, [@Charles query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16248822/939860) is most efficient.

More generally, you can use the window function [**`row_number()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html) to carry *any* order you like to the main query, including:

- order by columns *not* in the `SELECT` list of the subquery and thus not reproducible
- arbitrary ordering of *peers* according to `ORDER BY` criteria. Postgres will reuse the same arbitrary order in the window function *within* the subquery. (But *not* truly random order from `random()` for instance!)
  If you don't want to preserve arbitrary sort order of peers from the subquery, use `rank()` instead.

This may also be generally superior with complex queries or multiple query layers:

```sql
SELECT p.name
FROM  (
   SELECT name, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY <same order by criteria>) AS rn
   FROM   people
   WHERE  age >= 18
   ORDER  BY <any order by criteria>
   ) p
ORDER  BY p.rn
LIMIT  10;
```

Answer (score -2):

The are **not guaranteed** to be in the same order, though when you run it you might see that it is generally follows the order.

You should place the order by on the main query

```
SELECT name FROM
(SELECT name FROM people WHERE age >= 18) p
ORDER BY p.age DESC LIMIT 10
```