# Preserve order from subquery (with GROUP BY and ORDER BY)

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, sql-order-by

I am using a smartphone to collect data from the accelerometer and then saving it in a postgresql database, in a server. Basically, each time I read the accelerometer, I save the latitude/longitude at which the smartphone is at the moment, as well as the timestamp where it happened.

Now, I want to read from the database every distinct position (latitude/longitude) in the same order as they were saved (ordered by the timestamp). And I want to know how many readings are repeated in each position.

Let me explain with an example. Consider I have the following table in my database:

```
+------------+------------+-----------+
| latitude   | longitude  | timestamp |
+------------+------------+-----------+
| 43.1784771 | -8.5956853 | 930560045 |
| 43.1784771 | -8.5956853 | 930560054 |
| 41.2784813 | -7.5956853 | 930560063 |
| 42.1786173 | -8.5951757 | 930560072 |
| 42.1786173 | -8.5951757 | 930560082 |
+------------+------------+-----------|
```

Notice that I have the elements ordered by timestamp, and that I have 2 repeated positions.  So, I want to query the database to see the repeated positions and have the following result:

```
+------------+------------+-------+
| latitude   | longitude  | count |
+------------+------------+-------+
| 43.1784771 | -8.5956853 | 2     |
| 41.2784813 | -7.5956853 | 1     |
| 42.1786173 | -8.5951757 | 2     |
+------------+------------+-------|
```

The problem is that I want the elements ordered as the original table (ordered by timestamp).
I am trying the following query but it is not working, because the order in a subquery doesn't matter:

```sql
SELECT latitude, longitude, count(*)
FROM 
    (SELECT latitude, longitude, timestamp FROM table ORDER BY timestamp asc) subquery1
GROUP BY latitude, longitude
```

I have been looking in StackOverflow for answers and the closest was this one: [Is order in a subquery guaranteed to be preserved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248813/is-order-in-a-subquery-guaranteed-to-be-preserved)
However, it is not working in my case because I need the "group by" clause. Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: `SELECT latitude, longitude, count(*) from table GROUP BY latitude, longitude ORDER BY max(timestamp); /* or min(timestamp)*/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
latitude, 
longitude, 
count(1) as "Count", 
min(timestamp) as "Start",
max(timestamp) as "End"

FROM table 
GROUP BY latitude, longitude
ORDER BY min(timestamp) asc
```

Comment: The problem here is that you could be in the same location at two different time intervals. I, for example, go to work every day, and place my phone in the same exact global location from 9am to 5pm every day. This query, as you've described, does not show you that.

Comment: Hint: change `[...]` to `"..."`. It is PostgreSQL, not MS SQL server.

Comment: Actually, a very simples solution! Thanks! I am aware of the problem of same location at two different time intervals but it is not an issue in my specific problem by now.

Comment: @MaxSorin, the below answer by Abelisto solves the problem of same location at different time intervals :)

Answer (score 1):

```
create or replace function foo(
  out latitude numeric, 
  out longitude numeric,
  out cnt int,
  out start_time numeric,
  out end_time numeric
) returns setof record as $$
declare
  c record;
  p record;
  i int := 1;
begin
  select null into p;
  for c in (select * from table order by timestamp) 
  loop
    if p is null then
      start_time := c.timestamp;
    elsif p.latitude <> c.latitude and p.longitude <> c.longitude then
      latitude := p.latitude; 
      longitude := p.longitude;
      cnt := i;
      end_time := p.timestamp;
      return next;
      i := 1;
      start_time := p.timestamp;
    else
      i := i + 1;
    end if;
    p := c;
  end loop;
  if p.latitude = c.latitude and p.longitude = c.longitude then
    latitude := p.latitude; 
    longitude := p.longitude;
    cnt := i;
    end_time := p.timestamp;
    return next;
  end if;
  return;
end; $$ immutable language plpgsql;
```

Usage:

```
select * from foo();
```

As a little bonus it is also providing start/end timestamps for each series.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution has the advantage of separate same location at two distinct time intervals. In my specific case I don't need that, but it is indeed something good to point out!

Comment: @tjiagoM Feel free to use it if it will ever needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Ordering is not preserved for subqueries but it can be defined for array_agg operations and we can use that to determine a wider ordering. Try this for example:

```
SELECT latitude, longitude, count(*), (array_agg(timestamp order by timestamp))[1] as first_time
FROM table GROUP BY latitude, longitude;
```

In the OP's case, min(timestamp) might be simpler but if there is a more complex ordering this might be a neater option.