# How to use a subset of the row columns when converting to JSON?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-json

I have a table `t` with some columns `a`, `b` and `c`. I use the following query to convert rows to a JSON array of objects:

```
SELECT COALESCE(JSON_AGG(t ORDER BY c), '[]'::json)
FROM   t
```

This returns as expected:

```
[
  {
    "a": ...,
    "b": ...,
    "c": ...
  },
  {
    "a": ...,
    "b": ...,
    "c": ...
  }
]
```

Now I want the same result, but with only columns `a` and `b` in the output. I will still use column `c` for ordering. The best I came up with is as following:

```
SELECT COALESCE(JSON_AGG(JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('a', a, 'b', b) ORDER BY c), '[]'::json)
FROM   t

[
  {
    "a": ...,
    "b": ...
  },
  {
    "a": ...,
    "b": ...
  }
]
```

Although this works fine, I am wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this. It frustrates me that I have to manually define the JSON properties. Of course, I understand that I have to enumerate the columns `a` and `b`, but it's odd that I have to copy/paste the corresponding JSON property name, which is exactly the same as the column name anyway.

Is there a another way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use row_to_json instead of manually building object:

```
CREATE TABLE foobar (a text, b text, c text);

INSERT INTO foobar VALUES 
    ('1', 'LOREM', 'A'),
    ('2', 'LOREM', 'B'),
    ('3', 'LOREM', 'C');

--Using CTE
WITH tmp AS (
    SELECT a, b FROM foobar ORDER BY c
)
SELECT json_agg(row_to_json(t)) FROM tmp t

--Using subquery
SELECT 
    json_agg(row_to_json(t)) 
FROM 
    (SELECT a, b FROM foobar ORDER BY c) t;
```

**EDIT:** As you stated, result order is a strict requirement. In this case you could use a row constructor to build json object:

```
--Using a type to build json with desired keys
CREATE TYPE mytype AS (a text, b text);

SELECT 
    json_agg(
        to_json(
            CAST(
                ROW(a, b) AS mytype
            ) 
        )
    ORDER BY c) 
FROM 
    foobar;

--Ignoring column names...    
SELECT 
    json_agg(
        to_json(
            ROW(a, b) 
        )
    ORDER BY c) 
FROM 
    foobar;
```

SQL Fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3UdKM8UP1b4o97ej9AYG1H/0).

Comment: But this does not include the ordering on column `c`. Simply adding `ORDER BY c` in the CTE `tmp` or in the subquery is not correct, as you need to order in the outer query. So you need to add `c` to the projection in the CTE or subquery. But then you are back to the original question...

Comment: Why do you need ordering in outer query?

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248813/is-order-in-a-subquery-guaranteed-to-be-preserved

Comment: In this case the "anomaly" is because the LIMIT clause.

Comment: I am not an SQL expert, but I always understood that ordering of a subquery/CTE is not guaranteed to preserve in the outer query by SQL specification.

Comment: Indeed. But since you aren't doing filter neither group in outer query the query order likely will remain the same from inner.

Comment: Likely? That's dangerous. With the introduction of parallel query execution in latest PostgreSQL versions, you might get bitten by this quite quickly, I think.

Comment: Your update is a nice approach! I will be using that. Thank you for your ideas, much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to help you @schizofrenic_bit

Answer (score 0):

perform the ordering in a subquery or cte and then apply `json_agg`

```
SELECT COALESCE(JSON_AGG(t2), '[]'::json)
FROM (SELECT a, b FROM t ORDER BY c) t2
```

alternatively use jsonb. The jsonb type allows deletion of items by specifying their key

```
SELECT coalesce(jsonb_agg(row_to_json(t)::jsonb - 'c' 
                          order by c), '[]'::jsonb)
FROM t
```

Comment: I don't think that is correct. The `ORDER BY` must be done in the outer query as far as I know.

Comment: could you give me a counter example where this query returns a different result to yours. I tried with the following test data and got exactly the same result: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/17d54c/5

Comment: I am not an SQL expert, but I always understood that ordering of a subquery/CTE is not guaranteed preserved in the outer query by SQL specification. So it's dangerous/tricky to derive behavior from an ad-hoc fiddle.

Comment: see updated answer for alternate solution that doesn't rely on subquery ordering

Comment: That's a creative construction! But I don't think it's a desired solution performance wise.

Comment: @schizofrenic_bit: you are correct about the ordering. [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) "*Alternatively, supplying the input values from a sorted subquery will usually work .... Beware that this approach can fail if the outer query level contains additional processing*" - so the only _guaranteed_ way to get a defined sort order is to use on `order by` inside the aggregate function

Comment: @schizofrenic_bit, you stated that you were `wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this`. Just curious, how does my second solution perform in comparison to `SELECT COALESCE(JSON_AGG(JSON_BUILD_OBJECT('a', a, 'b', b) ORDER BY c), '[]'::json)
FROM   t`

Comment: @HaleemurAli Creating a JSONB to output a JSON seems too much overhead for me. There is no point in creating a JSONB if we aren't using it.